# How to rename Action/Anim in NLA editor?

Tags: animation, armature, nla-editor

I copied an existing "Run" animation to make a different variation of it, Blender auto renamed it to Run.001.

I can rename the Action itself on the left, to "Run_02", but I cannot find a way to rename the animation.

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not able to check right now but the first place I would look for something like this would be in the right-hand sidebar toolbox, [N] should bring it up (if they haven't changed the keybinding for that), or look for a little "+" near the top-right of the editor.  There may be a couple tabs to look through.

Answer (score 1):

As PGmath suggested:

1. Expanding the side menu that is hidden by that little arrow, will bring out a menu.
2. Now select the "Stri" tab.
3. The name is editable here.

[image]